# android -Why custom drawable not effecting textview

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable

this is my drawable code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

    <solid android:color="#3C1251" />
</shape>
```

This is a xml file called haraj.xml in my drawable folder .

This is my xml layout :

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/harajamount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/haraj"
        android:text="2500"
        />
```

Strangely it's not effecting textview. I get textview with no background color and no corners .

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put this text view inside any type of layout and set background for that layout.

Comment: @iffu not working , I've tried it

Comment: ok wait i ll work now and give u solution

Answer (score 0):

Whats your background right now? Hope it will not be the #3C1251. Because i have just try with your code. Its working perfect and giving proper background to textview with color.

[image]

Hope you might get any help. Let me know if its not working...

Enjoy Coding... :)

Comment: thanks for reply , no the background color is no the same, the main layout's background is white .still not showing :(

Comment: can you please share me your java code? You are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<corners android:radius="7dp"/>
```

instead of

```
<corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <solid android:color="#3C1251" />

    <size android:height="23dp" />

</shape>
```